# Fill space and ellipsize text

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a layout consisting of 2 textviews, aligned horizontally. The right textview should always display the whole text, and the left one should expand to take whatever space it needs, ellipsizing if it does not fit. When both views fit, the views should only take the minimum space.

These images illustrate what I'm after:

When all text fits:

[image]

When the left text is too long:

[image]

I have this starting layout, but I can't get it to work for both scenarios at the same time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        android:text="Left text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Right text"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating a packed chain with a bias of `0` to make it start-aligned and setting `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` for both `TextViews` so that their constraints are respected when wrapping content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="Left text"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/right"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="Right teasdasda asdsdsddddddd"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/left"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```